# JSOUP Find the ID of a DIV with specific class name

Tags: java, class, html, jsoup

How do extract the ID out of a div with a specific class name?

EX:

```
<div id="37849374" class="thread">
    Foo foo foo foo
</div>
<div id="28393842" class="thread">
    Doo doo doo doo
</div>
```

I'm thinking about falling back to regex and just proceeding that way.

Comment: I think I just answered my own question. it looks like `Elements.id()` will work.

Comment: Nope doesn't seem to work

Comment: I have to use `first()` to get the first of the elements then get the id

Comment: If you answered your own question, consider posting it as an answer and accepting it so future readers may benefit.

Answer (score 0):

First select all elements with **thread** class:

```
doc.select("div.thread")
```

Then use following method to remove the id attribute for each node:

```
public Node removeAttr(String attributeKey)
```

JSoup API: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/